# how to count a calling route from server in laravel

Tags: laravel, server, count, routes, click

Is there any ways to count a special route from another folder in server when it is calling in Laravel project?

For more information, I have below link in my laravel project:
The `application.apk` in in Android folder in server.

```
<li>
    <a href="/Android/application.apk" class="m-b-90"><i class="fab fa-android" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 20px;"></i><span>get android app</span></a>
</li>
```

how can I count number clicks on this link?

Comment: I suggest that on  click, you want that file to download. If that is the case, why not set that like to a controller's method. The method will insert a data into a table in your db anytime its clicked and you can access it by counting the num rows. At the end of the insert statement, you can redirect the person/user to the file for download. Let me know if you nee a code example

Comment: It didnt go to controller and It is placed in another folder in server. I set that link in our codes like example.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could add a special class that on click, it sums the click calling via Ajax a function inside a controller of laravel. Then it will sum that click wherever you want.